# I deleted my old account?

Tags: discussion

I had a post on [Zombie Game - Collision Detection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420165/zombie-game-collision-detection-issue). My profile some how got deleted or something. When I went to log in with facebook again it created a new profile. I cannot get back into user3349233. Can I merge this new one with user3349233?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the records, you deleted that account yourself.

To restore that account, [contact SE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) and request re-association of that account's content with your current account. Unfortunately, this is something even moderators cannot do.

Comment: Hmm I am not too worried about getting it back just getting the guys attention who is helping me. Is there a way I can PM him?